# Glade spinbutton: How to show default value as zero?

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3, glade

In Glade3 when I add a spinbutton I want to set its minimum value and default value as zero.

I did this by specifying the "Value" of the spinbutton as zero, as well as the "Value" and "Minimum value" of the adjustment to zero.

Upon testing, I can see that they are set to zero, however the zero value is not displayed on the spinbutton.

[image]

We can see here, when running the program, the left spinbutton shows its default value (which is 1) but the right spinbutton does not display 0.

If I edit the glade file manually to add `<property name="value">0</property>` to the spinbutton and run the program, it will show up correctly.

[image]

However, if I modify the file in glade, this line will be deleted by glade and the zero won't show up.

Is there anyway to show the zero as default value (using glade), or is this a bug in glade?

---

Edit: Minimal working example:

The xml file that Glade generates: (that doesn't work)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.16.1 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.10"/>
  <object class="GtkAdjustment" id="adjustment1">
    <property name="lower">1</property>
    <property name="upper">5</property>
    <property name="value">1</property>
    <property name="step_increment">1</property>
    <property name="page_increment">10</property>
  </object>
  <object class="GtkAdjustment" id="adjustment2">
    <property name="upper">59</property>
    <property name="step_increment">1</property>
    <property name="page_increment">10</property>
  </object>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window1">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkBox" id="box1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkSpinButton" id="spinbutton1">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="adjustment">adjustment1</property>
            <property name="value">1</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkSpinButton" id="spinbutton2">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="adjustment">adjustment2</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

How I want this xml file to look like: (that works)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.16.1 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.10"/>
  <object class="GtkAdjustment" id="adjustment1">
    <property name="lower">1</property>
    <property name="upper">5</property>
    <property name="value">1</property>
    <property name="step_increment">1</property>
    <property name="page_increment">10</property>
  </object>
  <object class="GtkAdjustment" id="adjustment2">
    <property name="lower">0</property>
    <property name="upper">59</property>
    <property name="value">0</property>
    <property name="step_increment">1</property>
    <property name="page_increment">10</property>
  </object>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window1">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkBox" id="box1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkSpinButton" id="spinbutton1">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="adjustment">adjustment1</property>
            <property name="value">1</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkSpinButton" id="spinbutton2">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="adjustment">adjustment2</property>
            <property name="value">0</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

If I manually change it to this file (with three lines added), it works perfectly fine and as expected. But if I open it up in Glade, change something and save, these three lines will be deleted by Glade automatically.

C code to compile:

```
// gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` mwe.c -o mwe `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`
#define builderfile "mwe.glade"
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    GtkBuilder *builder;
    GtkWidget *window;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
    builder = gtk_builder_new();
    gtk_builder_add_from_file(builder, builderfile, NULL);
    window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "window1"));

    g_object_unref(builder);
    gtk_widget_show(window);

    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What version of Glade?

Comment: @andlabs Glade 3.16.1

Comment: In glade 3.12.1 (current Debian Version) this works pretty good. Maybe there is a bug in that version of glade. Would it be possible to have your file to check it on my glade version? If this cause you troubles, think that you can also set the value of the spinbuttons on your script

Comment: The 'non working glade file' works pretty good in glade (3.12.1) and with the compiled C code. Some times the glade preview it is not the same than the one of the program. But don't worry! Your code works fine, and when you execute the C bin the zeros are displayed.

Comment: @rsm Then I guess my version of Glade is buggy. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Don't worry, and by the way, in the glade script that you posted, the main window is not set as <visible>. So when you run the script you actually don't see anything!. (It took me some minutes to figure it out since I don't program in C hehe)